# What happens to "jni" after APK is compiled

Tags: android, android-ndk

I was cherrypicking a mod from github for android source (ROM building, yeah).

The package in focus was SystemUI.apk

I noticed that the the process created a folder called `jni` in `SystemUI` folder which contained a C++ header file and a C++ programmed script. However, after the the package (SystemUI) was compiled, on decompiling it again with apktool, I didnt find  that `jni` folder.

Can anyone tell me what happened to it?

*Note:* It also added following lines to `Android.mk`:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    jni/com_android_systemui_statusbar_phone_BGUpdate.cpp

LOCAL_MODULE := SystemUI
```

Comment: `jni` is only source. You can find compiled lib in `lib` directory.

Comment: I guessed that much. But inside "system/lib" folder, there is no library that has "BGUpdate" or such in its name. But there is a "SystemUI.so" so I am guessing that must be it. So final query, if I wanted to use this library in some other package, will just moving this "SystemUI.so" to the "lib" folder in that package work (provided it needs and uses this library) (sorry kinda new to this stuff, so just want to know a little on how it works). Thanks for replying.

Comment: Thanks a lot, gonna try it :)

Comment: system/lib is unwritable and this directory contains only system libraries. You can load you lib using `System.loadLibrary("SystemUI");` And sorry i have a mistake with previous reply: `LOCAL_MODULE := SystemUI` is ok.